# reset default value of all input in a table no form included

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with input in it. There are input with default value and there are input without default value. I want to reset the input value into their default value on button click. I wont do the

```
$('#tableid').find('input[type=text]').val('');
```

Because as i said there are input with default value and i dont want to mess up the value of the input.

I also tried `reset()` like

```
$('#tableid').find('input[type=text]').reset();
```

but i get an error saying `reset is not a function`

Is there a way to `reset` the `input` inside the a `table without form`.

Comment: `find` should be `.find`

Comment: Why are you escaping double quotes in a single quoted string? `'input[type="text"]'` works fine.

Comment: sorry typo error @Magicprog.fr

Comment: If you use the `placeholder` attribute, resetting the value to `''` will work fine.

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xnch1pjv/) it may help you

Comment: Check this https://jsfiddle.net/2hpdjxac/

Comment: @Sadikhasan i check it thank you but i dont want an empty input i want the default value

Comment: @Pekka Check updated https://jsfiddle.net/2hpdjxac/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this : store default value as data in the input box as shown below

```
<input type="text" data-default="your default value" value="your default value">
```

and run below code on button click

```
$('#tableid').find('input[type=text]').each(function(){
      var defaultVal = $(this).data('default');
      $(this).val(defaultVal);
});
```

**Example**

```js
$(function(){
    $('#resetBtn').click(function(){
       $('#tableid').find('input[type=text]').each(function(){
      var defaultVal = $(this).data('default');
      $(this).val(defaultVal);
       });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableid">
    <tr><td><input type="text" data-default="first Default" value="first Default"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" data-default="Second Default" value="second Default"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" data-default="third Default" value="third Default"></td></tr>
</table>
        
<input type="button" value=" RESET " id="resetBtn">
```

Comment: i havent used `data-default` yet do i need to set it before hand?together with `value`?

Comment: In this case he will have to give the data-default attribute to each and every input tag.

Comment: @SwapnilPunekar, yes. But for input with no default value it will set empty space.

Comment: Yes thats very true. Good one!

Comment: one question what will happened if i dont put the  data-default attribute to each input

Comment: it will set empty space, see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7rzph27j/3/), here third input don't have default attribute

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the first HTML element by passing 0 to .get():

```
$('#tableid').find('input[type="text"]').get(0).reset();
```

Or (same but a bit shorter) :

```
$('#tableid').find('input[type="text"]')[0].reset();
```

Comment: i got this `$(...).find(...)[0].reset is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<table id="test">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" data-default="test1" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" data-default="test2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" data-default="test3" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button id="clickme">Click me</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#clickme").on("click",function(){
    $('#test').find('input[type=text]').each(function(){
        $(this).val($(this).attr("data-default"));
    });
});
```

**[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2hpdjxac/1/)**